# Setting margin programmatically to CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, layoutparams, android-layoutparams

I have a `CardView` in my XML layout and I need to set margins to it programmatically (This is because I don't need margin at all times. Based on few conditions, I either set or remove the margin).

Here's how I did it:

```java
CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams) myCardView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, SystemHelper.dpToPx(2), 0);
myCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This worked fine. It put `2dp` margin at the bottom of my `CardView`. However, I get this in my logcat:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

So I changed `CardView.LayoutParams` to `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, like this:

```java
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) myCardView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, SystemHelper.dpToPx(2), 0);
myCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

And yet again, it works but I get the same error as above.

So I modified it one more time to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

```java
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) myCardView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, SystemHelper.dpToPx(2), 0);
myCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

When I do this, I do NOT get the error however **it does not set any margin**.

Should I just ignore the error? It just doesn't seem right.

**EDIT:**

Here's my `CardView` in XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/item_min_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewAppointmentWeek"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ...

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show me the cardview in your xml code?

Comment: @red_allocator i've updated my question to show the `CardView` in xml

Comment: Who is the direct parent of your `CardView`?

Comment: @azizbekian `LinearLayout`. I've updated my question so you can see my layout

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In your case you are **not** specifically interested who is the parent of your `CardView`, because the only thing you want to change is the margin. All of the `*LayoutParams` classes are direct/indirect children of `MarginLayoutParams`, which means you can easily cast to `MarginLayoutParams` and perform change on that object:

```java
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams =
        (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) myCardView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, SystemHelper.dpToPx(2), 0);
myCardView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: This is not true for the `*LayoutParams` classes that are subclasses of `ViewGroup#LayoutParams`

Comment: Thank you for the solution, saved much of my time!

Answer (score 9):

1) Set the Cardview Parameters for it to be displayed programtically

Setting Carview Parameters

```
CardView cardView = new CardView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams cardViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
cardView.setLayoutParams(cardViewParams)
```

2) Set the Parameters for displaying the Margins around the cardview

Setting Params for Cardview Margins

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams cardViewMarginParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) cardView.getLayoutParams(); 
cardViewMarginParams.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 30);
cardView.requestLayout();  //Dont forget this line
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `Linearlayout` id your `CardView` child
2. Find `linearlayout` from `findViewById`.
3. Set `LayoutParams`

```java
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)myCardView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
```

Comment: I don't want to set padding. I want to set margin. It is completely different

Comment: You mean that LinearLayout have to move for margine?

Comment: No. I don't want to do anything with my `LinearLayout`. Please read my original question. I want to set `2dp` margin on my `CardView` programmatically.

Comment: You are setting margin to `LinearLayout`. I need to set it on `CardView` because `CardView` has a field called `cardElevation`. If `cardElevation` is set to `2dp`, shadow is not visible until you have a `2dp` margin at the bottom. So setting margin on `LinearLayout` doesn't help me

Comment: Are you serious? Padding is counted within the view's width and height and applied inside. Margin is counted outside the view's width and height and applied outside. Understand the question before you try to answer and tell someone else to understand something

Comment: cardview parent is LinearLayout
set padding Parent LInearLayout

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**
In kotlin layout margin set from code is tricky.

```
val cardView = CardView(context)
(cardView.layoutParams as? ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)?.leftMargin = 2
(cardView.layoutParams as? ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)?.bottomMargin = 2
cardView.requestLayout()
```