# Is there a way to put a margin between views programmatically in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Good day.
I'm new to android development and I am having a hard time setting margin for my view inside my kotlin file.

I tried all the guides I've seen but nothing seems to work.

Would someone take the time to check my code?

What I am trying to accomplish is inside a "for loop", I want to create a cardview with a textview inside and add it to the linear layout while adding some margin for each cardview.

This is my code:

```
package com.fangs.number_sorter_app

import android.app.ActionBar
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

class NumberSorterActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_sorter)




    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        val size = NumberHolder.getSize()
        val listOfNumbersLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_list_of_numbers)



        for (item in 1..size!!) {

            val newCardView = CardView(this)
            newCardView.foregroundGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
            newCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6200EE"))

            val text = TextView(this)
            text.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            text.text = "test"
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            newCardView.addView(text)
            listOfNumbersLayout.addView(newCardView,100,100)

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you and hope ya'll are doing great.

Edited:
I would just like to add this code change that I made:

```
import android.app.ActionBar
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

class NumberSorterActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_sorter)

    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        val size = NumberHolder.getSize()
        val listOfNumbersLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_list_of_numbers)



        for (item in 1..size!!) {

            val newCardView = CardView(this)
            newCardView.foregroundGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
            newCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6200EE"))

            val text = TextView(this)
            text.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            text.text = "test"
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            newCardView.addView(text)

            //get layout of newCardView
            val params = newCardView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            params.setMargins(10,10,10,10)
            //apply params
            newCardView.layoutParams = params

            listOfNumbersLayout.addView(newCardView,100,100)

        }

    }

}
```

I keep on having this error:

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
                at com.fangs.number_sorter_app.NumberSorterActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(NumberSorterActivity.kt:42)
               at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowFocusChanged(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:124)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting margin programmatically to CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223471/setting-margin-programmatically-to-cardview)

Comment: I tagged a question in Java, but it should not be hard to convert it to Kotlin

Comment: I did. But I keep on having this error ```java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        at com.fangs.number_sorter_app.NumberSorterActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(NumberSorterActivity.kt:37)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowFocusChanged(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:124) ```

Comment: Post your updated code in your question then, also attach the error message to your question (so it will be readable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is what is failing:

```kotlin
val params = newCardView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
```

This is because `newCardView.layoutParams` is returning `null`. The attempt to downcast `null` to `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` is what's causing your error.

You need to first create the layout params, and then set them:

```kotlin
val layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONENT)
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
newCardView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Comment: Thanks bud. I now understand where I'm getting that exception.